# Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error

Tags: java, android

How can I solve this problem, when I am building it, it is showing me the same problem-
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

I am using classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'

What should be the exact solution. Please let me know as soon as possible.

Comment: can you update your question with build.gradle file?

Comment: Can you post the whole build log? It should contain the actual error from AAPT2.

Answer (score 17):

There could be a problem in your res folders it could be an image that was not well converted so the solution to this is to update your gradle plugin which will highlight the actual problem

This line `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha18'`

Edit your build.gradle file:

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        google() // important!
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha18'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google() // important!
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**NOTE**  This might require to update your gradle to 4.6

Comment: Just upgrading to this gradle version saved my problem ! Amazing, this saved my day !

Comment: @sumit coolbuddy You should mark this as the correct answer, this will help others to find the correct answer faster

Comment: Upgrading gradle helped it listed all the xml files that were corrupt, I faced the issue when I renamed a variable text, this refactored android:text to android:te

Comment: I already had gradle updated to 4.6 but still build was failing with same error. Changing the Classpath to mentioned in answer created build successfully but can anyone explain this .. what happened by changing the classpath or a different version ?

Comment: adding the class path above definitely solved the issue but I also had to pay attention to the pop up message at the bottom that said it needed to update afterwards. I clicked it and it updated it.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue. Apparently this line had to be at the top of the main XML file and was 2 or 3 lines below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Cut and pasted to top of XML file and build succeeded.

Answer (score 4):

1. Open your build.gradle(app module)
2. Please make sure you have buildToolsVersion available in your gradle file (if it is missing please make sure you have to add (buildToolsVersion) same version as of compileSdkVersion)

Comment: Still not working ...com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Answer (score 4):

```
error: invalid file path 'F:\AK-Android-Code\ak-im\build\intermediates\manifests\aapt\enterpriseArmV7\release\output.json'.
error: invalid file path 'F:\AK-Android-Code\ak-im\build\intermediates\manifests\aapt\enterpriseArmV7\release\AndroidManifest.xml'.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':ak-im:verifyEnterpriseArmV7ReleaseResources'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
65 actionable tasks: 6 executed, 59 up-to-date
```

In my case,error info as above.I delete file folder F:\AK-Android-Code\ak-im\build\intermediates\manifests\aapt\ then rebuild project and it is successful. You can use ‘gradlew --debug assembleRelease ’ check gradlew's output info.

Comment: For me that didn't quite do the trick, but deleting the entire build dir did lol. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error:
>   check logs for details

Solve it in the following way in the Gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'+
```

this line

```
    aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
    aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem as you and solved this problem this way:

First, bulid a new "hello world" project in Android Studio and make sure it can correctly run.
Then, open the build.gradle file to check the classpath. In my "hello world" project, the classpath is

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
```

And then open the gradle-wrapper.properties file to check the distributionUrl.In my "hello world" project, the distributionUrl is

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

Finally, make the two configurations the same as "hello world" project in the imported project. The app could run correctly .

Comment: This is what worked for me. Upgrading to 3.5.0 required gradle 5.4.1 instead of default 4.10.3 for cordova-android@8.1.0

Comment: I solved mine the same way. First step, close the current project and use the wizard to create a new, minimal project. I used `File -> New -> New Project -> No Activity`. After I fixed that (with a couple of SO searches), I was able to return to my main project. It still didn't run, but I had narrowed it down to the real problem, which was that the app was already install as a 'device owner'.