# Error in Android Studio 3.1.3

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I just installed Android Studio 3.1.3. When I try to create a Project from the samples that Android Studio offers, an error occurs and I don't know what to do.
I didn't edit anything of the source code, just opened the sample and this is what I see.
If you need the full error please tell me, it is very long code.
[image]

this is the error if i don't expand anything

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
```

### RESOLVED BY MYSELF

Actually the problem was my User folder, it had non ascii character (ò) and AndroidStudio could not read it. Just changed user folder.

Comment: Please put the relevant parts of that error into the question as text. No one wants to read text output as a screencap. (Not to mention that the image text is nearly unreadable as it is.) Also, what research have you done? e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49709023/1531971 Show what steps you have taken to research this.

Comment: Can you please post your error log here?

Comment: Please post your error log, but by looking at your androidMainifest it seems that it is not determining your main activity.

Comment: Added the error log

Answer (score 0):

Basically this error is very clear that it has to do something with your gradle. Your are supposed to add each and every dependencies required for the app to run to be installed. Check all your dependencies are added properly and if you are using android 3.3 then make sure you are not using "compile" prefix to add dependencies. use "implementation" instead. This is though main cause of such error

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are connected to a good network

Try adding Google maven repository into app's build.gradle file:

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
}
```

If step 1 won't work, remove gradle from your project root folder and rebuild your project again.

**Try another**

> Goto >file -> other settings -> Under build, execution, and deployment
>   -> you will see Gradle. uncheck the checkbox offline work

Then synchronize

Comment: None of this worked for me. Could it be something with my user folder? It is "Nicolò", but in every project the "ò" is not read. I really don't know what to do

Answer (score 0):

while you are creating projects you must have a internt concectivity