# com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle

### Problem

It is working fine when i am building without release option. release option was working fine with android version 7.1.4

#### What is expected to happen?

it should build successfully

#### What does actually happen?

cordova build android --release

### Information

build gradle file:
https://gist.github.com/indraraj26/a6efaed1135b0e394a23a1b192bc2c0c

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.0-5013011-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during compile 'D:\client\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-land-xxxhdpi\screen.png', attempting to stop daemon. FAILED
20 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 19 up-to-date

  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s

D:\client>if "1" == "0" goto mainEnd

D:\client>rem Set variable GRADLE_EXIT_CONSOLE if you need the _script_ return code instead of

D:\client>rem the _cmd.exe /c_ return code!

D:\client>if not "" == "" exit 1

D:\client>exit /b 1
Command finished with error code 1: D:\client\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildRelease,-b,D:\client\platforms\android\build.gradle
D:\client\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.0-5013011-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during compile 'D:\client\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-land-xxxhdpi\screen.png', attempting to stop daemon.
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
Error: D:\client\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.3.0-5013011-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during compile 'D:\client\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-land-xxxhdpi\screen.png', attempting to stop daemon.
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (D:\client\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (D:\client\node_modules\cordova-common\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova.cmd build android --release --verbose exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

#### Command or Code

#### Environment, Platform, Device

#### Version information

```
ionic info
[WARN] Detected locally installed Ionic CLI, but it's too old--using global CLI.

Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 5.4.4 (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.2

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1, (and 15 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.8.1
   native-run  : 0.2.9

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.16.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.10.2
   OS                : Windows 10
```

with this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50973967/10842900 
i am able to build apk but getting this errors

```
D:\client\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-land-hdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-land-hdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
D:\client\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-land-ldpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-land-ldpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
D:\client\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-land-mdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-land-mdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
D:\client\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-land-xhdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
D:\client\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-land-xxhdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-land-xxhdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
D:\client\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-land-xxxhdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-land-xxxhdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
D:\client\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-port-hdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-port-hdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
D:\client\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-port-ldpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-port-ldpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
D:\client\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-port-mdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-port-mdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
D:\client\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-port-xhdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
D:\client\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-port-xxhdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-port-xxhdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
D:\client\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-port-xxxhdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-port-xxxhdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]

   Explanation for issues of type "MissingDefaultResource":
   If a resource is only defined in folders with qualifiers like -land or -en,
   and there is no default declaration in the base folder (layout or values
   etc), then the app will crash if that resource is accessed on a device
   where the device is in a configuration missing the given qualifier.

   As a special case, drawables do not have to be specified in the base
   folder; if there is a match in a density folder (such as drawable-mdpi)
   that image will be used and scaled. Note however that if you  only specify
   a drawable in a folder like drawable-en-hdpi, the app will crash in
   non-English locales.

   There may be scenarios where you have a resource, such as a -fr drawable,
   which is only referenced from some other resource with the same qualifiers
   (such as a -fr style), which itself has safe fallbacks. However, this still
   makes it possible for somebody to accidentally reference the drawable and
   crash, so it is safer to create a default dummy fallback in the base
   folder. Alternatively, you can suppress the issue by adding
   tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource" on the element.

   (This scenario frequently happens with string translations, where you might
   delete code and the corresponding resources, but forget to delete a
   translation. There is a dedicated issue id for that scenario, with the id
   ExtraTranslation.)

12 errors, 0 warnings
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this is failing is that there was a bug in aapt2's code for crunching (compressing) PNG files. PNG crunching is automatically disabled for debug builds, but turned on for release, that's why you only saw this in your release builds.

This has been fixed now, so just update your android gradle plugin version and you will get the aapt2 with the fix automatically. I'd suggest 3.5 or newer.

I also see you're on windows, so you might run into another issue that's common if you try to update to 3.5. Aapt2 daemons might fail to start - in that case you just need to install the Windows Universal C Runtime Library.

Comment: (updating will also fix the issue with the drawables, and if it doesn't then just add a dummy file res/drawable/screen.png - just make sure to not specify any densities or language configurations, just "drawable")

Comment: Thanks a lot. With 3.5 gradle it is working fine i had do it manually in android studio in order to get 5.4.1-all version

Comment: Me too, I had to upgrade gradle download URL to point to 5.4.1 after upgrading android gradle plugin from 3.3.0 to 3.5.0 (on cordova-android 8.1.0)